# ForEach сложение значений массива (JS)

Tags: суммирование, foreach, javascript

Подскажите есть ли более грамотное решение для сложения значений массива
Сейчас делаю так

```
count = [];
array.forEach(function(data, index){
count[index] = data.number;
});
eval(count.join('+'));
```

Выводит сумму (тут все норм), но так как я новичок в JS, возможно есть более грамотное и более правильное решение, а не клеить все через eval.

Пробовал разные варианты, но что то у меня не получилось добиться положительного эффекта.

Comment: Первое правило программирования на `javascript` - забудьте об `eval`

Comment: такое же правило можно и к PHP отнести =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var count = 0;
array.forEach(function(value, index) {
    count += +value;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Используйте [reduce](http://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#reduce-reduceright):

```
var sum = array.reduce(function (previousValue, value){
   return previousValue + value;
});
```